# Calculate the eigenvectors of this $2 \times 2$ matrix (problem because all equations result in $0=0$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

> What's the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix
>   $B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\  0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$?

The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^{2}-4\lambda+4=0$

The (double-)eigenvalue is $\lambda=2$

Now we want calculate the eigenvector with these, insert $\lambda=2$ here:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2-\lambda & 0\\ 
0         & 2-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So we have $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

I: $0x+0y=0$

II: $0x+0y=0$

But what would be the eigenvector now?

Can I randomly choose one myself? As example, would this be correct?

Eigenvector is $v= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}$.

---

An additional question, how would you write the eigenspace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for this matrix *every nonzero vector* is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$.

It is a bit of a detour in this case to find that by solving the characteristic polynomial -- but it is certainly a valid way to proceed, until you have the experience to recognize immediately how a matrix of this form behaves.

Generally what you would like to find in this case is a *basis* for the eigenspace (which in this case is the entire $\mathbb R^2$), so you should choose two linearly independent vectors. The simplest and most boring choice would be $(^1_0)$ and $(^0_1)$, but you can certainly also choose $(^1_2)$ and, for example $(^7_3)$ (or anything else that is not parallel to $(^1_2)$).

(Since question actually asks "what are the eigenvectors", a more strictly correct answer would be "every nonzero vector is an eigenvector" but giving a basis for the eigenspace is conventional and may be the kind of answer that's *expected* anyway).

Comment: When they ask for the basis of the eigenspace, what's meant by that? Is it the domain? So it would be a basis of the eigenspace if I wrote: $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @cnmesr: Yes -- haven't you seen the definition of a basis before? (A basis means a linearly independent set whose span is the subspace you're looking at). If you have not encountered the concept yet -- which would be a bit unusual but not impossible -- just ignore what I said about it.

Comment: We had tasks to check if a subspace forms a basis of a vector space. But I never had a task asking for a basis of something. That's why I was confused. So sorry for asking again but then what Peter wrote in the comment would also be a basis of the eigenspace? Or it would just be the eigenspace?

Comment: @cnmesr: No, $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is not a basis of anything -- it is not a linearly independent set. However $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis for the eigenspace, and $\{(1,2),(7,3)\}$ is also a basis for the eigenspace. A _subspace_ is never a basis; a basis is a certain kind of _subset_, but those subsets will not be subspaces.

Comment: This will be really my last question to you regarding this topic if you can reply, would this be a correct notation if I write the eigenspace like that: $E_{A}(2)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}| x,y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$? Or would this be better: $E_{A}(2)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}| \mathbb{R}^{2} \right\}$

Comment: @cnmesr: The first of those is the correct notation; the second is not ("$\mathbb R^2$" is not a property of $x$ and $y$). But you could _also_ just write $E_A(2)=\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, every non-zero vector $(x,y)$ is an eigenvector of $B$ to the eigenvalue $2$. This is because $Bx=2x$ holds for every vector $x$

Comment: Can I write it like that as sentence? How would you write the eigenspace?

Comment: The eigenspace is $\mathbb R ^2$ \ { $(0,0)$ }

Comment: @Peter: It is common to include the zero vector in the eigenspace even though it is not an eigenvector (see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenspace.html), such that it is a linear subspace, which is easier to work with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, makes sense. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pick the eigenvectors $\binom{1}{0}$ and $\binom{0}{1}$. These satisfy the given equations canonically: they form a standard basis for the family of eigenvectors in fact.

Yes, you can randomly choose one yourself. Don't forget a second, linearly independent one too.

The eigenspace is the span of the eigenvectors.

Comment: It's not enough if I just write one eigenvector for a double eigenvalue? I really need two eigenvectors here?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said not to forget a second eigenvector.

Comment: Alright good to know that too :)